# HTML5 Canvas is rendering non existing borders on different devices in Chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

**iOS Chrome Image**
[Without weird borders, like on desktop chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NbU1.jpg)

**Android Chrome Based Trusted Web Activity Image**
[With weird borders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD1da.jpg)

You can try for yourself if you get the borders or not on https://game.thelamdenrealm.com/ or the Play Store app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thelamdenrealm.game

Can some one explain this to me?

Im using drawImage like this on the canvas:

`ctx.drawImage(img, position[0], position[1], 64, 64);`

It draws a grid of 64x64px tiles.

I heard it might be something with the device pixel ratio but I still don't understand whats happening.

Comment: That's called antialiasing. Ensure you are drawing on integer coordinates (accounting for any scaling). If you want us to help more, you need to post more of your code.

Comment: Can't believe it, but you were right. I just put a parseInt around the positions and the borders went away.

Comment: Please create a answer that I can mark @Kaiido